# How to update a subset of recurring meetings in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I have a recurring meeting booked from May 1st, 2012 to Oct 31st 2012, with no room attached.  Is it possible to book a subset of the recurring events into a room, or do I have to do it one occurance at a time?  Using Microsoft Office Professional 2010

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply open your inital meeting that you have the existing reoccurance on, and add the room. There is also the possibility that your room or conference numbers might have been added by your exchnagne administrator as a resource. If that is the case then when you open your existing meeting, or create a new meeting, just make sure to add the room as a resource. The benefit to having rooms or meet me numbers listed as a resource is that it will then manage the calendar for those items, and notify anyone who atempts to book a schedule conflict...

Comment: My problem is that for a few of the dates the room is booked at that time.  As far as I can tell, if there is at least 1 conflict then you have to book each room seperatly if the meeting is already scheduled.  Pretty inconvenient.